# CARTO Analytics Toolbox for Snowflake - Functions disappeared

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been using **CARTO Analytics Toolbox for Snowflake** for quite some time but all of a sudden all the functions have disappeared.

[image]

What should I do in order to bring them back?

Kind Regards

Comment: I hadn't used this tool before, but just added it to my account from the marketplace and I'm able to see many functions - but no procedures - from this share.  This could be a permissions thing - by default, this installed with the public role for access.  Could it have been changed in your instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is javier from CARTO.

SOrry for the inconvenience. We have been reorganizing data shares and we don’t know if we might have affected something. Can you tell us the region your snowflake account is?

Also you can reach us at support@carto.com

Comment: my account is on `Azure`

Comment: My issue is resolved as `Snowflake technical team` helped me out. Seems to be there was an issue from the `CARTO` side (may be they were in the process of updating it).